# Updating posts' order with an SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress, postorder

I'm looking for a solution to add a post between two posts and save the new order in the database.

I added the order support for regular posts and I'm planning to use this field to order the posts in a page. The new posts are being created from the same page via AJAX. All the posts have same parent.

So I have:

1. PostA
2. PostB
3. PostC

Now I'd like to create a new post (PostD) between PostA and PostB. So the new order would be

1. PostA
2. PostD
3. PostB
4. PostC

So the order number would have to be updated for Posts B and C and PostD is assigned with order number 2 when the new PostD is saved.

I'm wondering, what would be the best solution for this. Maybe I could do an SQL query that would do something like this:

*get all posts with post parent XX and with order number >= new post number and add +1 to these posts' order numbers.*

Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: See transactions. Step 1. Update the ordering reference of every row with an ordering reference >= 2. Step 2. Insert the new row. I assume that the Post column is your PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: Simply add a timestamp column? (Then the order is unimportant.)

Comment: @jarlh Are you feeling OK?

Comment: @Strawberry, well, perhaps too much multi-tasking... Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 0):

Use steps of 10000.

Algorithm:

- If new post after last - *order number* set to last *number* + 10000
- Else get arithmetical mean *order number* between *before* and *after* posts
- If no free numbers between posts - run full renumbering posts branch. After it insert new row.

Renumbering query:

```
update posts
   set number=(select @i:=@i+10000)
 where (select @i:=1)=1 and (condition_for_select_posts_branch)
 order by number
```

Answer (score -1):

always use steps of 10, so you have room for 9 extra posts inbetween..

Comment: What about the 10th post?

Comment: Hey why -1? It's a solution to the question asked. I agree that it's not the most elegant way, but it gets the job done

Comment: Sorry, but this is not really what I asked... Thanks anyway!